# How to set circle mask using geq filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I can creat rectangle mask but not creat circle mask.
What do I set geq filter options?

rectangle mask setting

```
ffplay -f lavfi color,geq='st(0,between(X,W/3,2*W/3)*between(Y,H/3,2*H/3));ld(0)*255:128:128'
```

circle mask image sample

[image]

Comment: I can supply a command later but basic idea is to implement the eq (for a solid circle): (X,Y) - C <= R. The trouble is that since the eq is a real-valued function and image addressing in pixels is quantized to integer steps, the circle will have a fairly jagged edge. One workaround is to create a much larger canvas, apply geq and then scale it down. Other is to use drawtext to draw a dot/period with a very large font size.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi color,geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),80*80),255,0)':128:128
```

to create a disc of radius 80 pixels centered at the frame's center. Replace `W/2` and `H/2` with co-ordinates or different expressions to shift the disc.